# Temporarily storing statistics on slave in Django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-1.8

My slave servers collect statistics and performance metrics about visits, but eventually they would have to be sent to the master DB.

I don't want to have a permanent database connection open with the master DB server, so they would have to be temporarily stored locally and shipped over in chunks at specific intervals.

Any suggestions for tools to do this with Django? I've come up with the idea of storing the records in a local SQLite DB and sending them to the main DB server every hour for example. But maybe there are better ways than SQLite out there. Also, still not sure, for pushing the data back into the master DB server at regular intervals, would you use a direct DB connection from within Django, or design a simple API to send it over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

I'll end up using redis and putting them in a list, prickling the objects. Main advantage: no SQLite migrations to maintain. It's really a pain though that Redis doesn't support atomic gets for more than 1 item, like LPOP but for more than 1, to retrieve them in batches...